# Alternative to using for loop for performing logic on multiple pandas series with using shift/offset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and created the following function for calculating the Relative Strength Index (an indicator for stock markets). I have a pandas series containing averages and want to perform a modification using the values from another series and need to use the offset value from the series itself.

I now use a for loop, iterating through all the values in the series and having access to the index which does the job. But I was wondering if there was a way to get the same result using an apply method or something similar which would make the code cleaner.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import yfinance as yf 

def yahoo_rsi(data:pd.DataFrame, period:int=14, column:str="Close"):

       delta = data[column].diff()
       delta = delta[1:]
       up = delta.clip(lower=0)
       down = delta.clip(upper=0)
       up[ up < 0 ] = 0
       down[down > 0] = 0

       down = down.abs()

       avg_ups:pd.Series = up.ewm(span=period).mean()
       avg_downs:pd.Series = down.abs().ewm(span=period).mean()

       alpha:float = 1/period

       # This is the for loop i would like cleaner

       for x in range(period+1, len(avg_ups)):
           avg_ups[x] = up[x]*alpha+(1-alpha)*avg_ups[x-1]
           avg_downs[x] = down[x]*alpha+(1-alpha)*avg_downs[x-1]

       rsis:pd.Series = pd.Series(100 - (100/(1+avg_ups/avg_downs)), avg_ups.index)
       return rsis


def run():
   ticker = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
   df = ticker.history("1d","1d", date(2022, 2, 2), date(2022, 8, 2), 
   prepost=True,auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False)
   yahoo_rsi(df)

run()
```

I have tried the following but it did not give the desired result because I believe it uses the old values of the series in stead of the updates ones, which it needs.

```
avg_ups[period+1::] = up[period+1::]*alpha+(1-alpha)*avg_ups[period+1::].shift(1)
avg_downs[period+1::] = down[period+1::]*alpha+(1-alpha)*avg_downs[period+1::].shift(1)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.shift()`?

Comment: @BeRT2me I have tried shift() but I believe it uses the old values in the series in stead of the updated ones, which I need. If i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sounds like a `numba` problem~